# Reading Terraform outputs from a YAML pipeline and use it in the deployment stage

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  name: terraformOutput
  inputs:
   provider: 'azurerm'
   command: 'output'
   workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
   environmentServiceNameAzureRM: service_connection
```

This task is giving the output in json (not in output.json file), how can I extract this and use it in a separate stage for the app deployment?

Comment: Please add the error/problem to the question.

Comment: Could you share with us whole relevant part of your workflow. This is really important to figure out proper syntax for accessing output variables.

Comment: You're using `webapp_name` when trying to access the variable but setting `appservice_name`.

Comment: Your task where you set variable is not named. This also could be the case.

Answer (score 2):

To save output to json file you should use `custom` settings:

```
- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'output'
    outputTo: 'file'
    fileName: 'output.json'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'rg-the-code-manual'
```

Then you could use this bash snippet:

```
    output=$(jq 'to_entries|map([.key] + [.value.value] + [.value.sensitive])' output.json | jq -c '.[]')
    for row in $(echo "${output}" ); do

        variable=$(echo "${row}" | jq -r '.[0]')
        value=$(echo "${row}" | jq -r '.[1]')
        isSecret=$(echo "${row}" | jq -r '.[2]')

        echo "Creating variable ${variable}"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${variable};isSecret=${isSecret}]${value}"
        
    done
```

It will create variable and secret variable based on outputs you have.

Comment: The task TerraformTaskV4@4 doesn't give the command option to generate the file in json, but it is printing the whole result as json.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-terraform/tree/main/Tasks/TerraformTask/TerraformTaskV4) is written than `output` is supported.

Comment: Yes, but it gives the output in the console than in a json file.

Comment: You need to use `custom` and then you can use output and save it as file.

Comment: You can actually reduce your bash snippet to a single line. `jq -r 'to_entries[] | "echo \"Creating variable \(.key)\"; echo \"##vso[task.setvariable variable=\(.key);isSecret=\(.value.sensitive)]\(.value.value)\""' output.json | sh` . This line gets all values from json file and sets them as variables to be used in other processes.